# no data returned from URLSession

Tags: json, swift, api, http

I performed this same request on Postman, and it works fine. However here the data is empty when I run this URLSession (see DATA EMPTY tag):

```
import Foundation

struct PhotoResponse: Decodable {
    let results: [Photo]
}

class PhotoInteractor {
    static var shared = PhotoInteractor()
    var error: Error?

    func getPhotos(query: String, completionHandler: @escaping ([Photo], Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=o&page=1&per_page=30&") else {
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("Client-ID \(Config.shared.accessKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            //*** DATA EMPTY!!! ***
            if let data = data, let photos = self.photosFromJSONResponse(data) {
                completionHandler(photos, nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func photosFromJSONResponse(_ data: Data) -> [Photo]? {

        do {
            let photoResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(PhotoResponse.self, from: data)
            return photoResponse.results
        } catch {
            self.error = error
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: any error ?????????

Comment: @Sh_Khan no error, 200 status in response

Comment: make sure accessKey it is not optional and/or nil

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried hard coding it in.

Comment: @LeoDabus I've been stuck on this all day